# RealmSwift LinkingObjects and Decodable

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a Realm model class that I need to be Decodable so I can serialize it from JSON and save it to database. Every `PortfolioItem` is associated with one `Product` and at some point I need to get to `PortfolioItem` from `Product` via inverse relationship. That's why I have `LinkingObjects` property. The problem is when I try to conform to `Decodable` protocol. The compiler is giving me an error `Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'LinkingObjects<PortfolioItem>' does not conform to 'Decodable'` . How to deal with this? I found very little about LinkingObjects and Decodable online and I have no idea how to approach this.

```
class PortfolioItem: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var productId: String = ""

    @objc dynamic public var product: Product?

    convenience init(id: String, productId: String) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
    }

}

final class Product: Object, Decodable {

    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

    private let portfolioItems = LinkingObjects(fromType: PortfolioItem.self, property: "product")

    public var portfolioItem: PortfolioItem? {
        return portfolioItems.first
    }

    convenience init(id: String, name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

Big thanks to Chris Shaw for helping me figure this out. I wrote a more in-depth article how to setup Decodable and LinkingObjects, [look HERE](https://medium.com/@patrickroh/serializing-json-into-realm-database-with-linkingobjects-12be9bccf7da).

Comment: Part of the issue is it's not a primitive (String, Num, bool etc) so you'll need to include extra code for this use case. Are you trying to use `JSONDecoder().decode(`?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to do that that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well unless I'm missing something then the `LinkingObjects` properties does not need to be included in the decoding.

My assumption here is that you're receiving JSON from some online source, where the JSON for a `Product` consists of { id: "", name: "" }. As long as you're creating the `PortfolioItem` correctly with associated `Product`, then the resulting `LinkingObjects` property is the result of a dynamic query within Realm (and will thus work without any JSON source).

I'm not in a position to test compile an answer today, but you should be able to use CodingKeys to simply exclude that property, i.e. by adding this to `Product`:-

```
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case name
}
```

Also, unrelated, but note that your `convenience init` function are not initialising all properties that you're passing in.

Comment: Wow, awesome answer. This works correctly, be sure to modify the `convenience init`  to include `self.name = name`