# Proper Class Structure for JSON being pushed into local realm

Tags: swift, realm, decodable

Okay so basically what I am trying to do is pull sneaker data from an api that I made which holds data about various sneakers. The json structure looks something like this.

```
  sneakers {
        bramds {
             nike
                 nikeshoe1
                 nikeshoe2
                 ......
            jordan
                 jordanshoe1
                 jordanshoe2
                 ......
}
}
```

I want to create a class in swift that inherits the decodable class so that I can parse and deserialize the json and pass it to realm. I looked at this guide but I am still a little stuck on the modeling part. Currently what I have is something like this

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift


struct Sneaker: Decodable {
    var brands : [Brands]

}

struct Brands: Decodable {
    var brandName: String
    var shoe: [Shoe]

}

struct Shoe:Decodable {

    var productlink: String
    var productlinkhref: String
    var name: String
    var price: String
    var releasedate: String
    var colorway: String
    var brand: String
    var designer: String
    var technology: String
    var maincolor: String
    var silhouette: String
    var nickname: String
    var category: String
    var imagesrc: String

}
```

Im just trying to figure out if im on the right track as far as making these models decodable based off of my JSON Structure. In addition to that what would be the proper syntax for pushing decodable objects to realm, would it be the same syntax? I have included a sample of my JSON as well below any help is appreacited

```
{
"sneakers": {
  "brands" : {
    "Air Jordan": [
      {
            "webscraperorder": "1554084909-97",
            "webscraperstarturl": "https://www.goat.com/sneakers",
            "productlink": "$200AIR JORDAN 6 RETRO 'INFRARED' 2019",
            "productlinkhref": "https://www.goat.com/sneakers/air-jordan-6-retro-black-infrared-384664-060",
            "name": "Air Jordan 6 Retro 'Infrared' 2019",
            "price": "Buy New - $200",
            "description": "The 2019 edition of the Air Jordan 6 Retro ‘Infrared’ is true to the original colorway, which Michael Jordan wore when he captured his first NBA title. Dressed primarily in black nubuck with a reflective 3M layer underneath, the mid-top features Infrared accents on the midsole, heel tab and lace lock. Nike Air branding adorns the heel and sockliner, an OG detail last seen on the 2000 retro.",
            "releasedate": "2019-02-16",
            "colorway": "Black/Infrared 23-Black",
            "brand": "Air Jordan",
            "designer": "Tinker Hatfield",
            "technology": "Air",
            "maincolor": "Black",
            "silhouette": "Air Jordan 6",
            "nickname": "Infrared",
            "category": "lifestyle",
            "imagesrc": "https://image.goat.com/crop/1250/attachments/product_template_additional_pictures/images/018/675/318/original/464372_01.jpg.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "web-scraper-order": "1554084911-110",
            "webscraperstarturl": "https://www.goat.com/sneakers",
            "productlink": "NewMar 30$160AIR JORDAN 1 RETRO HIGH OG 'PHANTOM'",
            "productlinkhref": "https://www.goat.com/sneakers/air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-black-phantom-555088-160",
            "name": "Air Jordan 1 Retro High OG 'Phantom'",
            "price": "Buy New - $160",
            "description": "Instead of the usual two-tone color blocking, the Air Jordan 1 Retro High OG ‘Phantom’ makes use of contrast stitching in black and red to distinguish the high-top’s clean lines. The shoe’s all-leather upper is finished in off-white Sail, accented by a padded collar and underlayer Swoosh in University Red. True to its OG designation, the design is finished with Nike Air branding on the woven tongue tag and insole.",
            "releasedate": "2019-03-30",
            "colorway": "Sail/Black-Phantom-University Red",
            "brand": "Air Jordan",
            "designer": "Peter Moore",
            "technology": "Air",
            "maincolor": "White",
            "silhouette": "Air Jordan 1",
            "nickname": "Phantom",
            "category": "lifestyle",
            "imagesrc": "https://image.goat.com/crop/1250/attachments/product_template_additional_pictures/images/020/095/781/original/411931_06.jpg.jpeg"
        }
```

If I neglected some details please let me know.

Comment: This is not a code review site.  You should go to a different Stack Exchange Network web site.

Comment: @ElTomato thanks for your help

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384960/realmswift-linkingobjects-and-decodable) question and answer as it may provide some direction for your structure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if you're on the right track, but have you looked at the Apple examples?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types

I found the downloadable playground quite helpful.

Also, since you get to design the JSON, you have the freedom to make the JSON mirror the Swift data structure you want. So I'd work backwards from that.